# Looking to create a google form that pulls questions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm working on an employee KPI scorecard, we currently use excel however we would like to use google sheets for greater ease of access and viewability.
[image: current google sheet]

We currently have a dashboard like the one above for every employee in separate tabs. Every employee has different goals and scores. Currently each user logs in an types a, p or n and each letter has a score associated with it. We would like to make this easier by creating a front end form they fill out each month that populates this google sheet.

where the KPI is set dynamically as the question per user and month.

Preferably each user would have login to access there dashboard.

If any one knows of a way to dynamically pull questions from a google sheet that would be great...if anyone knows of a better way that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, for example, how about using Web Apps? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: just looking to see if a similar solution already exist...